# Docker --output in Github Actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a Dockerfile that creates a file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2 AS base

RUN mkdir /output && touch /output/hello.txt

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/hello.txt /
```

if I build the Dockerfile locally with

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --output . .
```

I have my `hello.txt` file in my folder as expected. But if I do the same through Github Actions as

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout 
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v1
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

  - name: Run
    run: |
      docker build -f Dockerfile --output . .
 
  - name: Check
    run: |
      ls -la
```

the file is not in the folder. Do you know how can I retrieve the Dockerfile output through github actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [custom build output](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs) functionality you are using is available with the Buildkit backend. To use the Buildkit backend over the classic backend you either can:

1. Specify `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` when running the docker command
2. Set it in the docker engine by default by adding `"features": { "buildkit": true }` to the root of the config json.
3. Use `docker buildx` as you are attempting

Docker buildx is being set up in the Github Actions so just have to replace `docker build` with `docker buildx build`.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout 
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v1
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

  - name: Run Buildx
    run: |
      docker buildx build -f Dockerfile --output . .
 
  - name: Check
    run: |
      ls -la
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem perfectly. It's a pity that it's so difficult to find this topic, I think it should be promoted somehow.